# Как передать React.createRef компоненте Textarea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент `Textarea`:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';    
import './textarea.scss';

export default function Textarea(props) {
  const {
    className,
    placeholder,
    onChange,
    ref,
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  return (
    <textarea
      className={classNames('textarea', className)}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={onChange}
      ref={ref}
      {...restProps}
    />
  );
}
```

Я хочу передать ему `ref`, чтобы можно было вывести вводимый текст, но при передаче компоненту `Textarea` ссылки `ref`, он видит в ней `undefined`:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';    
import Button from '../../components/button';
import Textarea from '../../components/textarea';    
import './profile.scss';

export default function Profile(props) {
  const {
    className,
    state
  } = props;

  const addPostElement = React.createRef();

  const addPost = () => {
    alert(addPostElement.current.value);
  }

  return (
      <div
        className={classNames('profile', className)}>
          <form className="profile__add-post">
            <Textarea
              className="profile__add-post-input"
              placeholder="What's happening?"
              ref={addPostElement}
            />
            <Button
              className="profile__add-post-button"
              caption="Add post"
              onClick={addPost}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Если использовать стандартный `textarea` в форме, то все работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу передать `ref` конкретно самой компоненте?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html):

```
const Textarea = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <textarea ref={ref} />
))
```